# NaN among the classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-science

I am trying to do a Linear Regression on a data set on applications and the label I assigned was the rating of the application. When trying to split the label into classes, there was a third class 'NaN' even though it was not specified.

```
bins = (2, 3, 5)
group_names = ['bad', 'good']
appStore['user_rating'] = pd.cut(appStore['user_rating'], bins = bins, labels = group_names)
appStore['user_rating'].unique()
```

results to

```
[good, bad, NaN]
Categories (2, object): [bad < good]
```

I even ran the code

```
appStore.isnull().sum()
```

and it shows no null, the results for all fields were 0.

EDIT:
I even edited the bins to bins = (0, 3, 5) to split the data because the minimum in the column was 0 and the maximum was 5. It still had a NaN.

This is the result when I ran sns.countplot(appStore['user_rating']):
[image]

As you can see there would've been no outlier data.

Comment: Please my updated answer below.

Comment: Note to the **EDIT**: Because the bin edges downwards exclusive and upwards inclusive i.e. `0` will not be the element of the `0` edged bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [pandas.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) method we can define bins with **bin edges** as you did:

```
bins = (2, 3, 5)
```

means that we defines two valid categories:

One category with the values falling between **(2 and 3)** and another between **(3 and 5)**.
Every value's category outside these categories will be `NaN`

The problem is, that your data contain values, which are outside of the intervals you defined. I demonstrate it with an example:

```
import pandas as pd

appStore = pd.DataFrame()
appStore['user_rating'] = [2.3, 3.3, 4, 6]

bins = (2, 3, 5)
group_names = ['bad', 'good']
appStore['user_rating'] = pd.cut(appStore['user_rating'], bins=bins, labels=group_names)
print(appStore['user_rating'].unique())

print()
print(appStore)
```

**Out:**

```
[bad, good, NaN]
Categories (2, object): [bad < good]

  user_rating
0         bad
1        good
2        good
3         NaN
```

As you see `6` doesn't fall neither between **(2 and 3)** nor between **(3 and 5)**.
So basicaly you have no labels for the outlier data, that is why `pandas` substituted one missing labels value with `NaN` for it.

If you don't have such outlier in your data, then the problem doesn't occur:

```
import pandas as pd

appStore = pd.DataFrame()
appStore['user_rating'] = [2.3, 3.3, 4, 4.5]

bins = (2, 3, 5)
group_names = ['bad', 'good']
appStore['user_rating'] = pd.cut(appStore['user_rating'], bins=bins, labels=group_names)
print(appStore['user_rating'].unique())

print()
print(appStore)
```

**Out:**

```
[bad, good]
Categories (2, object): [bad < good]

  user_rating
0         bad
1        good
2        good
3        good
```

**Note:** the bin edges **downwards exclusive** and **upwards inclusive** e.g. the `(1,2,3)` edges defined bins will not contain `1`(it will be categorized as `NaN`), but will `3` as `(2-3)`.

Comment: Please check my updated question. There are no data outliers.

Comment: Ok, I have solved it myself. I just found out that the first parameter is not included in the splitting. So I had to do it like: bins = (-1, 3, 5) to include all data with value 0.

Comment: @TheOneBruce I checked and you have more outliers, not just the `0` like: `0, 1, 1.5` and even the `2`.